# getting NXDOMAIN, but more-verbose host lookups are working

Tags: domain-name-system

i could not log into a server via SSH:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname apex.swiftinit.org: Name or service not known
```

i get the same error with `dig`:

```
$ dig +tcp apex.swiftinit.org CNAME

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> +tcp apex.swiftinit.org CNAME
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 54807
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;apex.swiftinit.org.        IN  CNAME

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
swiftinit.org.      2368    IN  SOA dns1.registrar-servers.com. hostmaster.registrar-servers.com. 1710114605 43200 3600 604800 3601

;; Query time: 28 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (TCP)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 10 19:11:29 CDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 120
```

however, if i specify the authoritative name server, the DNS lookup succeeds:

```
$ dig +tcp @dns1.registrar-servers.com apex.swiftinit.org CNAME

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> +tcp @dns1.registrar-servers.com apex.swiftinit.org CNAME
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 3179
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;apex.swiftinit.org.        IN  CNAME

;; ANSWER SECTION:
apex.swiftinit.org. 1799    IN  CNAME   swiftinit-lb-e810d5e23487605d.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

;; Query time: 76 msec
;; SERVER: 156.154.132.200#53(dns1.registrar-servers.com) (TCP)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 10 19:12:32 CDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 107
```

i tried clearing the local DNS cache with `sudo resolvectl flush-caches` this had no impact on the result.

if it helps, DNS over UDP is **not** working for some reason:

```
$ dig @dns1.registrar-servers.com apex.swiftinit.org CNAME

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> @dns1.registrar-servers.com apex.swiftinit.org CNAME
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 10116
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;apex.swiftinit.org.        IN  CNAME

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
swiftinit.org.      2160    IN  SOA dns1.registrar-servers.com. hostmaster.registrar-servers.com. 1710114605 43200 3600 604800 3601

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 156.154.132.200#53(dns1.registrar-servers.com) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 10 19:14:57 CDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 109
```

what could i possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Try again tomorrow.